# 2002 Sonata that accelerates on its own and with braking seems like shift lockup. Also at a complete stop the car is still reving

Tags: transmission, hyundai, sonata

I'm not sure if the crankshaft sensor failing, No CEL.  My car did this last night. Ishut it off gave it dry gas topped off tranny fluid about 2ounces.  Ran it and it was smooth, shifted normally no irratic accelerations.  What is wrong with this car it was like it couldn't keep proper timing, everything was off a beat.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to diagnose without more information, but it could be that your throttle plate was stuck open. This *might* explain:

- the engine revving even after the engine coming to a stop (fuel injection management compensates for more air by adding more fuel)
- the feeling that the engine is running rough (misfiring in the event of a lean condition, while the fuel injection management is still in the process of correcting the lean condition)

---

### What could cause the throttle plate to get stuck like that?

- ***carbon build-up on the back of the throttle plate***

  The fix will involve just cleaning off the carbon build-up after gaining access to the back of the plate.

  [image: CBU on Throttle body]
- ***if cable-operated, maybe the cable or spring has snagged on something***